# Lua require chunk environment

Tags: lua, require

A required chunk runs in global environment by default.

Each loaded user script is setup to run in a sandbox and if the script happens to contain a require call, it will modify the global environment.

Is there a way to set that environment to the same one of the calling script?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replace `require` with your own function.

The [prosody](https://prosody.im) XMPP server does this [here](http://hg.prosody.im/0.10/file/70e65ac65219/prosody#l149).